# MYSQL select column value when two rows have same condition

Tags: mysql

I need get value if two rows have same value. I need get post_id one field 145 in output.
[image]

Should i use JOIN or not? Or maybe some simpler/faster way to do this?

But this is not correct one...But i need someting like this, when barcode and _sku values are SAME.

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'barcode' = '_sku' AND meta_value = '123';
```

Getting error and checking just barcode field...
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '_sku'

Comment: could you please explain what you are doing `meta_key = 'barcode' = '_sku'`  for?

Comment: This is not correct sql. I need get output when barcode and _sku are same

Comment: Explain what constitutes "same".